# Material UI Icons not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons, material-ui

I'm sorry to ask this again but I cannot for the life of me find out what is going on. I am moving my React app inside an angular app and have got everything working except for the material-ui/icons They are there, they just do not look as they should!

I'm using the most current packages I have the link to the styles in my index.html file and I believe I'm using the Icons correctly.

```
import { Close } from '@material-ui/icons'

<Close />
```

This is what they look like on my app.
[Bad Icons Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tiw98.png)

I don't have any console errors pertaining to material-ui or the Icons.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

`import Close from '@material-ui/icons/Close'`

Try this too:

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';

<Icon>close</Icon>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just tried both of those methods and no luck :( Alo those radio buttons and checkboxes use the material icons by default and I'm actually not importing the icons them selves in the particular image that I added

Comment: did you install the package ? `npm install @material-ui/icons`

Comment: I lied. It did work when I tried it the second way. Do you know of a way to make it so the checkboxes, radio buttons, table-pagination, etc work this way and not the default method?

Comment: and yes I have that package installed.

Comment: "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",

Answer (score 0):

If your environment doesn't support tree-shaking, the recommended way to import the icons is the following:

```
import Close from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
```

If your environment support tree-shaking you can also import the icons this way:

```
import { Close } from '@material-ui/icons';
```

Importing named exports in this way will result in the code for every icon being included in your project, so is not recommended unless you configure tree-shaking. It may also impact Hot Module Reload performance if you enable it.

To enable tree shaking [click me](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)